Change Face-api.js landmarks pointColor
This is my code and i want to Change pointColor and lineColor but i don't know how?
I am using fast-api.js library and i don't found any sample with customized Landmarks Styles.
export const drawResults = async (image, canvas, results, type) => {
      if (image && canvas && results) {
        const imgSize = image.getBoundingClientRect();
        const displaySize = { width: imgSize.width, height: imgSize.height };
        faceapi.matchDimensions(canvas, displaySize);
        canvas.getContext('2d').clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
        const resizedDetections = faceapi.resizeResults(results, displaySize);
    
        switch (type) {
          case 'landmarks':
            faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections);
            break;
          case 'expressions':
            faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
            break;
          case 'box':
            faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
            break;
          case 'boxLandmarks':
            faceapi.draw.drawDetections(canvas, resizedDetections);
            faceapi.draw.drawFaceExpressions(canvas, resizedDetections);
            faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections);
            break;
          default:
            break;
        }
      }
    };
    ```


make use of the drawFaceLandmarks function in faceapi to make customized drawline,linecolor and so on


 // Custom options for drawing landmarks
    const drawOptions = {
      drawLines: true, // Enable drawing lines between points
      lineColor: 'red', // Custom line color
      pointColor: 'blue', // Custom point color
    };



pass the drawOptions object in the drawfacelandmark function
like


faceapi.draw.drawFaceLandmarks(canvas, resizedDetections, drawOptions);



